# Excel VBA: Regular Expression - get file name

Tags: excel, vba

How do I get just filename (without path and extension) 

like "MyFileName"

from the following full path?

C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt

Comment: Split on \ and take the last element of the array.

Comment: It's like code golf :) Tim's suggestion is similar to this `y = Split(x, "\"): f = y(UBound(y))` where x is the full path

Comment: Any reason why you specified a regexp (given the simple options from Tim and Dick)?

Answer (score 2):

`InStrRev` will find the last occurrence of a character in a string. Search for `\` and split it there

```
FullFileName="C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt"
FileName=mid(FullFileName,instrrev(FullFileName,"\")+1)
```

now to take off the extension

```
FileNameWithoutExt=left(FileName,instrrev(FileName,".")-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function GetFileNameWithoutExt(ByVal fullPath As String) As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileNameWithoutExt As String

Dim lastSlash As Integer
Dim positionOfDot As Integer

lastSlash = InStrRev(fullPath, "\")
fileName = Mid(fullPath, lastSlash + 1)

positionOfDot = InStr(1, fileName, ".")
fileNameWithoutExt = Mid(fileName, 1, positionOfDot - 1)

GetFileNameWithoutExt = fileNameWithoutExt
End Function
```

Using the immediate window

```
?GetFileNameWithoutExt("C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt")
```

**EDIT**: Another method

```
Public Function GetFileNameWithoutExt2(ByVal fullPath As String) As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim splittedData
Dim fileNameWithoutExt As String

splittedData = Split(fullPath, "\")
fileName = splittedData(UBound(splittedData))

fileNameWithoutExt = Split(fileName, ".")(0)

GetFileNameWithoutExt2 = fileNameWithoutExt
End Function
```

Comment: the 2nd method will fail for a filename like `MyReport11.12.2012.txt`

Comment: @SeanCheshire: Yes. The code has certain assumptions in it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: Yes, I have not used regex to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a real file that you have access to, you can use Dir

```
sFileOnly = Dir(sPathAndFile)
```

If it's not a real file or you don't have access to it, this will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = ".*\\"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
filename = regEx.Replace(fullpath, "")
```

Comment: hi thank you @m4573r how will regex greediness affect this expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Test()
        Dim fileNameOnly As String
        fileNameOnly = Left$(Split("C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt", "\")(UBound(Split("C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt", "\"))), InStrRev(Split("C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt", "\")(UBound(Split("C:\A_B\C.D\E_\F0123456789\G\MyFileName.txt", "\"))), ".") - 1)
        Debug.Print Strtf    
    End Sub
```