# Extract the file name and extension in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .xls file and want to extract the file name and extension from the cells using a VBA macro. Example:

```
c:\Documents\One.psd
```

I need the name in separate variable and psd in separate variable.

Regards

Satish

Comment: Have you looked at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354592/excel-vba-regular-expression-get-file-name)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
   s = Range("A1").Value
   ary = Split(s, "\")
   bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ".")
   fname = bry(0)
   ext = bry(1)
   MsgBox fname & vbCrLf & ext
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get parts of file paths is with the Scripting Runtime's FileSystemObject:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim filepath As String

filepath = "C:\Somewhere\foo.bar"

'Outputs "C:\Somewhere"
Debug.Print fso.GetParentFolderName(filepath)
'Outputs "foo.bar"
Debug.Print fso.GetFileName(filepath)
'Outputs "foo"
Debug.Print fso.GetBaseName(filepath)
'Outputs "bar"
Debug.Print fso.GetExtensionName(filepath)
```